# Is it possible to make macros that are default arguments expand at call site?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, default-arguments, std-source-location

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int a = __LINE__){printf("hello %d\n", a);}

void main(){
  print();
  print();
  print();
  print();
}
```

The `__LINE__` macro in this case expands to 3, so the print function is called 4 times with the same value. Is there a way to convince the compiler to expand this macro at the callsite, so that the print function would be called with `6,7,8,9` instead of `3,3,3,3` with features that exist in C++11?

**My usecase:**

In my application, I provide multiple functions that take a unique ID. The ID should be unique per callsite/location (so if the function is called two times throught the same statement, it should receive the same id). Currently, the user always has to manually type a `LOCATION` macro at the callsite, like this:

```
#define S1(x) #x //voodoo to concat __FILE__ and __LINE__
#define S2(x) S1(x)
#define LOCATION __FILE__ S2(__LINE__)

do_stuff1(arguments, LOCATION)
do_stuff2(arguments, LOCATION)
```

It would be more convenient if I could save them the typing, without creating a macro for each function like this:

```
#define do_stuff1(do_stuff1_imp(arguments, LOCATION))
#define do_stuff2(do_stuff2_imp(arguments, LOCATION))
```

Hence I thought a default argument would do the trick. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Do the work in a macro, `#define print() {printf("hello %d\n", __LINE__);}`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote in the last code block, only translated on `do_stuff` instead of `print`. I am aware of this solution and wanted to know if there was a less tedious way to do this (I have quite a lot of these functions. I would need to make a macro for each of them).

Comment: Wait, no, sorry I was wrong. Your way makes the whole function a macro. That is indeed different. I will consider that, thanks!

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Don't change the tags from C++ to C like that. Even if all of the code in the question would compile with a C compiler, that doesn't make the question a C question (note that default arguments are a C++ feature). The OP is using a C++ compiler and is looking for C++ answers, not C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The `__LINE__` macro in this case expands to 3*

Sure because your function declaration is done at line 3 and the prepreprocessor expands it from there.

Another macro instead of a function declaration would do the trick well (taken from [@Ejay's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399081/is-it-possible-to-make-macros-that-are-default-arguments-expand-at-call-site/53399194#comment93673421_53399081)):

```
#define print() printf("hello %d\n", __LINE__)
```

See a working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba99ed963ee4cca5).

Comment: @Jarod42 Done that.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be looking for [`std::experimental::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location), which will be `std::source_location` in a future standard:

```
#include <experimental/source_location>

void print(std::experimental::source_location const& location
    = std::experimental::source_location())
{
    printf("hello %s:%d\n", location.file_name(), location.line());
}
```

Comment: This is indeed exactly what I was looking for. I will not be able to use C++17 though (which this requires I think?). Sorry, I forgot to mention this in the question. I will keep this in mind for the future though. Thanks!

Comment: @pulp_user It doesn't require C++17, it requires that your standard library / compiler implements at least this part of the library fundamentals TS v2. You can try it and see if it works, else look at the documentation for your compiler / standard library to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can write a macro which inserts the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` into the argument list:

```
// Note: this doesn't work with a 0-argument function. Supporting 0-arg functions
// is much harder to do; I'd recommend just having a separate macro like as follows
#define LOCATED(fn, ...) fn(__VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __LINE__)

#define LOCATED0(fn) fn(__FILE__, __LINE__)

void print(char const* file_name, int line)
{
    printf("hello %s:%d\n", file_name, line);
}

int do_something(int value, char const* file_name, int line);

int main() {
    LOCATED0(print);
    LOCATED(do_something, 42);
}
```

With a little more work, you can make it look nicer at the call-site:

```
#define LOCATED(...) LOCATED_##__VA_ARGS__

void print(char const* file_name, int line)
{
    printf("hello %s:%d\n", file_name, line);
}
#define LOCATED_print() ::print(__FILE__, __LINE__)

int do_something(int value, char const* file_name, int line);
#define LOCATED_do_something(value) ::do_something(value, __FILE__, __LINE__)

int main() {
    LOCATED(print());
    LOCATED(do_something(42));
}
```

Comment: I fail to see how this is different from `print(LOCATION)` (how I currently do it in my code) besides turning it inside out.

Comment: @pulp_user You are right that it's not better than `print(LOCATION)`, but it's an alternative